# Transpose a pandas dataframe with headers as column and not index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

When I transpose a dataframe, the headers are considered as "index" by default. But I want it to be a column and not an index. How do I achieve this ?

```
import pandas as pd
dict = {'col-a': [97, 98, 99],
        'col-b': [34, 35, 36],
        'col-c': [24, 25, 26]}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
print(df.T)

        0   1   2
col-a  97  98  99
col-b  34  35  36
col-c  24  25  26
```

Desired Output:

```
        0   1   2   3
  0  col-a  97  98  99
  1  col-b  34  35  36
  2  col-c  24  25  26
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and then set default columns names:

```
df1 = df.T.reset_index()
df1.columns = np.arange(len(df1.columns))
print (df1)
       0   1   2   3
0  col-a  97  98  99
1  col-b  34  35  36
2  col-c  24  25  26
```

Another solution:

```
print (df.rename_axis(0, axis=1).rename(lambda x: x + 1).T.reset_index())
#alternative
#print (df.T.rename_axis(0).rename(columns = lambda x: x + 1).reset_index())
       0   1   2   3
0  col-a  97  98  99
1  col-b  34  35  36
2  col-c  24  25  26
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `T` with `reset_index`:

```
df=df.T.reset_index()
print(df)
```

Or:

```
df.T.reset_index(inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Both Output:

```
   index   0   1   2
0  col-a  97  98  99
1  col-b  34  35  36
2  col-c  24  25  26
```

If care about column names, add this to the code:

```
df.columns=range(4)
```

Or:

```
it=iter(range(4))
df=df.rename(columns=lambda x: next(it))
```

Or if don't know number of columns:

```
df.columns=range(len(df.columns))
```

Or:

```
it=iter(range(len(df.columns)))
df=df.rename(columns=lambda x: next(it))
```

All Output:

```
       0   1   2   3
0  col-a  97  98  99
1  col-b  34  35  36
2  col-c  24  25  26
```